# Converting a dynamic piece of code using WordPress Loop into a static one using Post ID

Tags: posts, functions, loop, post-meta

```
<?php  
if (is_single()) { ?>
<?php $imvi = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 't_puck_imvi', true); ?>
<div class="class1" <?php if( 'none' === $imvi) { ?> style="display:none;" <?php } ?>>
    <div class="<?php if( 'show_vi' === $imvi  ||  'show_im' === $imvi) {echo 'video';} ?>">
        <?php if( 'show_vi' === $imvi || 'show_vint' === $imvi ) { ?>
            <div>
            <?php
                    // some code here
             ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if( 'show_image' === $imvi || 'show_image_notext' === $imvi ) {
            the_post_thumbnail( 'large');
        }
        ?>
    </div>  
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Above is a code that is executed in single.php within a WordPress loop. All good No Issues.

But I want to achieve something else.

Instead, I want to make this code executed somewhere on the front page, but not within a loop but based on some particular post. so I believe we need to use the ID of that post, Right?

so I believe the secret lies somewhere here:

```
<?php $imvi = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 't_puck_imvi', true); ?>
```

can you guide me how to achieve this w/o loop, but by some specific Post ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a dynamic piece of code into a static one is a pretty straight forward task. It's the other way that is complex.

Any WordPress function that can accept `get_the_ID()`, can also accept a string as an ID. Some even accept arrays.

So, simply turning

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 't_puck_imvi', true);
```

to

```
get_post_meta( 123 , 't_puck_imvi', true);
```

Will do the job.

### Note

Not all the functions that can be used withing a loop accept a post ID. An example would be [`the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/) function that only takes a size as its input. In such cases, there are most likely an equal function to use, such as [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail_url/).